# In the proof of that Complete convergence is equivalent to convergence a.s. under independence

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

[Complete convergence is equivalent to convergence a.s. under independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508069/complete-convergence-is-equivalent-to-convergence-a-s-under-independence)

In here, it uses the second Borel-cantelli lemma for the converse.

But, it is necessary to verify that $(X_n - X)$'s  are independent.

(We only have $X_n$'s are independent and $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s.)

How it can be derived??

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence $(X_n)$ is independent and $X_n\to X$ almost surely then $X$ is an almost sure constant. Hence the sequence $(X_n-X)$ is independent.